# In nfc reader sample application where is come payload data in intent of tagviewer

Tags: android

```
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
```

when i debug application raw Msgs value is following below,

`[NdefMessage [NdefRecord tnf=1 type=5370 payload=D1010B5501676F6F676C652E636F6D]] data`

where is come from this value thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra NDEF_MESSAGES is a parameter of one of the NFC disovery intents (NDEF_DICOVERED/TECH_DISCOVERED). The data can come either from an NFC tag (in that case the NFC tag holds the NDEF data structure in its memory) or from another peer-to-peer NFC device (in that case the NDEF data structure had been transfered over either SNEP or NPP).

The TECH_DISCOVERED intent only triggers for NFC tags, while the NDEF_DICOVERED intent triggers for both tags and peer-to-peer communication.

Btw. the data contained in your NDEF message is a single NDEF URI record containing the URI http://www.google.com/

Comment: u mean when nfc tag read it store in  NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES

Comment: Yes, when the scanned tag contains NDEF formatted data and your app gets triggered by one of the NFC discovery intents, the NDEF message is pre-read and stored in that intent extra.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
u mean nfc tag it automatically store in intent .reason for asking that i am beginner in android and i have no real device so concept is clear then later on i purchase device so that i confidense for develop application

Comment: As I wrote before: Whenever an Android device detects a tag that contains NDEF formatted data, it automatically reads this data. Next it tries to trigger applications that expect this data based on their intent filters and finally it tries to trigger apps based on the more general TECH_(/TAG_) intent filters. Whenever one of the NFC-specific intents NDEF_/TECH_(/TAG_) is fired, that intent also contains any NDEF messages that were priviously automatically read from the tag.